# I don't have python but I have python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently formatted my laptop and installed the Ubuntu operating system. I did not explicitly install Python. To check if it is pre-installed, I ran `python --version` in the terminal and got this:

```
$ python --version
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3       
sudo apt install python        
sudo apt install python-minimal

You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

Then I checked `python3 --version` and got this: `Python 3.6.9`.

How is this possible? Should I install `python` as well? Or can I continue to use `python3`? Would this cause any problems?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use Python 3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recent Ubuntu versions do not install python  2 by default, as python 2 is now "dead". However, the command `python` is *not* (yet) linked to python 3, to avoid some confusion; traditionally, `python` was for python 2 while `python3` was for python 3.

In case you want to change this behavior and use `python` to run python 3, try installing a package named 'python-is-python3'. Then you can run `python --version` and see that it points to python 3.

In theory it *might* cause confusion for some legacy programs, but I haven't seen any issue so far for about a year.

> In 20.04 LTS, the python included in the base system is Python 3.8. Python 2.7 has been moved to universe and is not included by default in any new installs.
>
> Remaining packages in Ubuntu which require Python 2.7 have been updated to use /usr/bin/python2 as their interpreter, and /usr/bin/python is not present by default on any new installs. On systems upgraded from previous releases, /usr/bin/python will continue to point to python2 for compatibility. Users who require /usr/bin/python for compatibility on newly-installed systems are encouraged to install the python-is-python3 package, for a /usr/bin/python pointing to python3 instead.
>
> — https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

Comment: so this means there is no need to install python on my system, since the python3 is installed by default, right?  of course I will install anaconda later and through that I will install which version of python I want. but the question is why I can not run my python scripts in vs code? I can not even select interpreter

Comment: yes, but there were no such an option at all. I dis not take screeshot of the error and I do not remember it. btw I installed anaconda and through it I launch vs code and run my codes, but my question is still valid. sinve I had python3 installed by default why vs code could not run my scripts?

Answer (score 5):

Just `python` on Linux traditionally refers to Python 2. `python3` is the correct command if you want to use Python 3 (which you should, as Python 2  is EOL).

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: Just use python3

Python on Ubuntu refers to Python v2. If you were to run
`python --version`
you would see an output in the format of
`Python 2.x.y`

[Python 2 has been sunset](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), which means it no longer will be updated and the recommendation is to move to Python3.

To run a program with Python 3, you just need to use python3 command instead.

`python3 ./app.py`